# Papa Rudin definition

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

**There is the definition:**

Thus, generally speaking, sets of measure $0$ are negligible in integration.
It ought to be true that every subset of a negligible set is negligible.
But it may happen that some set $N$ $\in$ $\mathfrak M $ with $\mu(N)$ $=$ $0$ has a subset $E$ which is not a member of $\mathfrak M $.

How is it possible that  $N$ $\in$ $\mathfrak M$ and the subset of $N$ ( what's inside of $N$) is n't in $\mathfrak M$ ?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I don't have the book in front of me, but what was $\mathfrak M$?  A sigma-algebra?  You can have a sigma algebra over $X$ which is not the full powerset of $X$.  For example $\{\emptyset,\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{1,2,3,4\}\}$ is a perfectly valid sigma algebra, and we could have a measure where $\{1,2\}$ has measure zero.  That does not imply that $\{1\}$ is a set with measure zero however since $\{1\}$ isn't even a valid element of the sigma algebra to begin with.

Comment: I would expect John Nash to understand this.

Comment: From $A\subseteq N\in\mathfrak M$ you cannot conclude in general that $A\in\mathfrak M$. Simple example: $\mathbb Q\subseteq\mathbb R\in\{\varnothing,\mathbb R\}$ but $\mathbb Q\notin\{\varnothing,\mathbb R\}$.

Comment: ℚ∉{∅,ℝ} why? @drhab

Comment: $\{\varnothing, \mathbb R\}$ is a set that has exactly two elements, which are $\varnothing$ and $\mathbb R$. But $\mathbb Q\neq\varnothing$ and $\mathbb Q\neq\mathbb R$. That means that $\mathbb Q$ is **not** an element of $\{\varnothing, \mathbb R\}$. That fact is denoted by: $\mathbb Q\notin\{\varnothing, \mathbb R\}$.